# How do I get a specific value from a line in powershell

Tags: powershell, bitlocker

I'm trying to get a specific value out of the `manage-bde -status C:` command, which returns the following:
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.18362
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Volume C: []
[OS Volume]

```
Size:                 237.29 GB
BitLocker Version:    None
Conversion Status:    Fully Decrypted
Percentage Encrypted: 0.0%
Encryption Method:    None
Protection Status:    Protection Off
Lock Status:          Unlocked
Identification Field: None
Key Protectors:       None Found
```

I'm trying to get the end of the line labelled *Protection Status* and return *Off*

Comment: I would use `Get-BitLockerVolume` instead, `manage-bde` just returns a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, I would use `Get-BitLockerVolume` instead as it returns an object which is easier to query:

```
Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint C: | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProtectionStatus
```

Comment: Hi @DanielThomas, if my response answered your question please mark it as the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to check if it matches Off under Protection Status?
If so, here is an ugly piece of code I did it fast, but can get you what you want:

```
$status = manage-bde -status C: | Select-String 'Protection'
if ($status -match 'Off'){
Write-Output $true
} else {
Write-Host $false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used something similar to the post above to determine if BitLocker had been enabled over a drive from the manufacture which will always have unknown or none in the identification field.

```
# Check for OEM configuration of BitLocker

$blidfield = manage-bde -status C: | Select-String 'Identification Field'
$bloemencrypted = manage-bde -status C: | Select-String 'Conversion Status'
if ($blidfield -match 'None' -or $blidfield -match 'Unknown' -and ($bloemencrypted -match 'Fully Encrypted' -or $bloemencrypted -match 'Used Space Only Encrypted')){
    Write-Log "BitLocker appears to be configured with OEM configuration, Starting to decrypt."
    manage-bde -off C:
    exit
} else {
    Write-Log "BitLocker doesn't appear to be configured with OEM configuration"
}
```

Please note that the line 'manage-bde -off C:' will decrypt the OS drive.